# union tables where date

Tags: sql, oracle, union, date-range

I need to query 2 tables in an Oracle database. One is a current table, the other is historical, with virtually the same headers. I want to be able to have a union on the query, but just a single date range. 
An simple example of what I'm trying to do might be a better explanation:

```
select order_number, insertdate        
from do_table      
where insertdate between '1-apr-17' and '8-apr-17'   
union  
select order_number, insertdate  
from doi_table  
where insertdate between '1-apr-17' and '8-apr-17'
```

can it be written like this?

```
select order_number, insertdate  
from do_table  
union  
select order_number, insertdate  
from doi_table  
where insertdate between '1-apr-17' and '8-apr-17'
```

The date range queried changes a lot and the query is quite big, and just for ease, I want the user running the query to be able to enter the date range once.

Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want use where only once you need to create a subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select order_number, insertdate  
    from do_table  
    union  
    select order_number, insertdate  
    from doi_table  
    ) T
WHERE insertdate between '1-apr-17' and '8-apr-17'
```

But I dont recomend it because then you wont be able to benefit from the index on the insertdate field. Your first query is ok, Just use the user parameter twice

Answer (score 1):

One method for handling this is to use a `params` CTE:

```
with params as (
      select date '2017-04-01' as date1, date '2017-04-08' as date2
      from dual
     )
select t.order_number, t.insertdate        
from params cross join do_table t     
where t.insertdate between params.date1 and params.date2 
union all
select t.order_number, t.insertdate  
from params cross join doi_table  t 
where t.insertdate between params.date1 and params.date2 ;
```

Note that I changed the `union` to a `union all`.  `union` incurs extra overhead for removing duplicates.  If you intend that, then use `union`.  But by default, `union all` is better.

I should add that in my experience, such a `params` CTE is fine from a performance perspective, but there could be exceptions.

Comment: I know English is my first language. But `CTE is find from a performance` doesn't sound ok. Not sure if you are saying is good or bad for performance.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . I'm guessing that English is *not* your first language.  Regardless, "d" is right next to "e" on the keyboard.